# How should I compare memory usage between two processes?

Tags: linux, process, memory

I have two processes that I'd like to compare the memory of and find out which one was more memory intensive (using `/proc/[pid]/status` in Linux). However, I'm confused as to how to interpret some of the fields (not what they mean - I know what each field represents).

1. For both processes, `VmPeak` is 4505 kB. Does that mean they used the same amount of memory? Since virtual memory encompasses RAM, swap, etc., is this the field to pay attention to?
2. `VmRSS` is 704 kB on process A, while it is 740 kb on process B. Does this mean processes B was more intensive, as more memory was allocated in physcial RAM? In addition, B is higher on `RSSAnon`, `RSSFile`, but lower on `VmPTE`, if that factors in in any way.
3. B has 200 voluntary context switches, while A has 1083. How does this fit into the picture of memory consumption?

I suppose the real issue here is my lack of knowledge on memory, not anything else, so I apologize for any ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

"Voluntary context switches" are moments in which the process yields the CPU voluntarily. That is done essentially each time a system call is made. Involuntary switches are due to e.g. a page fault, the process has to wait for a resource and gets the CPU taken away. No relation to memory usage.

You are looking at peak usage. But it is clearly very different if the process uses e.g. 1 MiB for most of it's runtime, and ocasionaly peaks at 4 MiB for short periods of time, or uses 3 MiB constantly. And even that is misleading, the program could have 4 MiB asigned, but really uses 1 MiB actively while the other part is inactive. That part could be swapped out, and make no difference.

Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? It is better to measure the performance data what really interests you and compare, not trying to break it down.

Comment: I wasn't looking for anything specific, I just need a general way to check which one overall was more memory-intensive. Is there a different way for me to measure that you would recommend?